# Entity Framework Core - Domain-driven design - Adding child entity to aggregate root

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to implement an aggregate root of a restaurant table that has child entities of orders with Entity Framework Core 7 as the underlying persistence infrastructure.

The table already exists in the SQL database and I'm trying to call a "use" command on it.

The "use" method on the table aggregate root creates the order and add it to the table's collection of orders.

However, I'm getting a `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException` exception because the order entity is getting treated by EF as an update and not an add (it seems to be inheriting the entity state of it's table parent).

I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/infrastructure-persistence-layer-implementation-entity-framework-core) article and have tried to apply it in my `TableConfiguration`, but it doesn't appear to be working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

**Exception**

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ThrowAggregateUpdateConcurrencyExceptionAsync(RelationalDataReader reader, Int32 commandIndex, Int32 expectedRowsAffected, Int32 rowsAffected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeResultSetAsync(Int32 startCommandIndex, RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeAsync(RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Update.Internal.SqlServerModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Sample.Restaurant.Application.Tables.UseTableCommand.UseTableCommandHandler.Handle(UseTableCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\src\Lewee\sample\Sample.Restaurant.Application\Tables\UseTableCommand.cs:line 51
   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPostProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPreProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Lewee.Application.Mediation.Behaviors.FailureLoggingBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\src\Lewee\src\Lewee.Application\Mediation\Behaviors\FailureLoggingBehavior.cs:line 20
   at Lewee.Application.Mediation.Behaviors.ValidationBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\src\Lewee\src\Lewee.Application\Mediation\Behaviors\ValidationBehavior.cs:line 36
   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionActionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionActionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPostProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPreProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Sample.Restaurant.App.Pages.Index.UseTable(Int32 tableNumber) in C:\src\Lewee\sample\Sample.Restaurant.App\Pages\Index.razor.cs:line 24
   at Sample.Restaurant.App.Pages.Index.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<<BuildRenderTree>b__2>d.MoveNext() in C:\src\Lewee\sample\Sample.Restaurant.App\Pages\Index.razor:line 39
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
```

**BaseEntity**

```cs
public abstract class BaseEntity : IEntity, ISoftDeleteEntity
{
    protected BaseEntity()
        : this(Guid.NewGuid())
    {
    }

    protected BaseEntity(Guid id)
    {
        this.Id = id;

        // Note audit fields should be popualated by EF save changes interceptor
        this.CreatedBy = "System";
        this.ModifiedBy = "System";
        this.CreatedAtUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
        this.ModifiedAtUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;

        this.DomainEvents = new DomainEventsCollection();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; private set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAtUtc { get; private set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; private set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedAtUtc { get; private set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; protected set; }
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; protected set; } = default!;
    public DomainEventsCollection DomainEvents { get; protected set; }

    public void ApplyCreationTrackingData(string? createdBy)
    {
        this.CreatedBy = createdBy ?? "System";
        this.CreatedAtUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
        this.ApplyModificationTrackingData(createdBy);
    }

    public void ApplyModificationTrackingData(string? modifiedBy)
    {
        this.ModifiedBy = modifiedBy ?? "System";
        this.ModifiedAtUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

**Table Aggregate Root**

```cs
public class Table : BaseEntity, IAggregateRoot
{
    private readonly List<Order> orders;

    public Table(Guid id, int tableNumber)
        : base(id)
    {
        this.orders = new List<Order>();
        this.Orders = this.orders;

        this.TableNumber = tableNumber;
    }

    public Order? CurrentOrder => this.orders
        .Where(x => x.OrderStatusId != Contracts.OrderStatus.Paid)
        .Where(x => !x.IsDeleted)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAtUtc)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    public int TableNumber { get; protected set; }
    public bool IsInUse { get; protected set; }
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Order> Orders { get; protected set; }

    public void Use(Guid correlationId)
    {
        if (this.IsInUse)
        {
            throw new DomainException("Table is already being used");
        }

        this.IsInUse = true;

        this.orders.Add(new Order(this, correlationId));

        this.DomainEvents.Raise(new TableInUseDomainEvent(correlationId, this.Id, this.TableNumber));
    }
}
```

**Order Entity**

```cs
public class Order : BaseEntity
{
    internal Order(Table table, Guid correlationId)
    {
        this.TableId = table.Id;
        this.Table = table;

        this.DomainEvents.Raise(new OrderCreatedDomainEvent(
            correlationId,
            this.Id,
            table.Id,
            table.TableNumber,
            DateTime.UtcNow));
    }

    // EF Constructor
    private Order()
    {
        this.TableId = Guid.Empty;
        this.Table = new Table(this.TableId, 0);
    }

    public Guid TableId { get; protected set; }
    public Table Table { get; protected set; }
}
```

**Table DB Configuration**

```cs
internal sealed class TableConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Table>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Table> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

        builder.Property(x => x.CreatedBy)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(255);

        builder.Property(x => x.ModifiedBy)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(255);

        builder.Property(x => x.Timestamp)
            .IsRowVersion();

        builder.Ignore(x => x.DomainEvents);

        builder.HasIndex(x => x.TableNumber)
            .IsUnique();

        builder.Ignore(x => x.CurrentOrder);

        builder.Metadata
            .FindNavigation(nameof(Table.Orders))
            ?.SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
    }
}
```

**Order DB Configuration**

```cs
internal class OrderConfiguration : BaseEntityConfiguration<Order>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Table> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

        builder.Property(x => x.CreatedBy)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(255);

        builder.Property(x => x.ModifiedBy)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(255);

        builder.Property(x => x.Timestamp)
            .IsRowVersion();

        builder.Ignore(x => x.DomainEvents);

        builder.HasOne(x => x.OrderStatus);

        builder.HasOne(x => x.Table)
            .WithMany(x => x.Orders)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.TableId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

** Database Context**

```cs
public class RestaurantDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IAuthenticatedUserService authenticatedUserService;

    public RestaurantDbContext(DbContextOptions<RestaurantDbContext> options, IAuthenticatedUserService authenticatedUserService)
        : base(options)
    {
        this.authenticatedUserService = authenticatedUserService;
    }

    public DbSet<Table>? Tables { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new TableConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new OrderConfiguration());
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

        optionsBuilder.AddInterceptors(new AuditDetailsSaveChangesInterceptor(this.authenticatedUserService));
        optionsBuilder.AddInterceptors(new DomainEventSaveChangesInterceptor<RestaurantDbContext>());
    }
}
```

**Use Table Command**

```cs
public sealed class UseTableCommand : ICommand
{
    public UseTableCommand(Guid correlationId, int tableNumber)
    {
        this.CorrelationId = correlationId;
        this.TableNumber = tableNumber;
    }

    public Guid? TenantId { get; }
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; }
    public int TableNumber { get; }

    internal class UseTableCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<UseTableCommand, CommandResult>
    {
        private readonly IRestaurantDbContext dbContext;
        private readonly ILogger logger;

        public UseTableCommandHandler(IRestaurantDbContext dbContext, ILogger logger)
        {
            this.dbContext = dbContext;
            this.logger = logger.ForContext<UseTableCommandHandler>();
        }

        public async Task<CommandResult> Handle(UseTableCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            using (LogContext.PushProperty(nameof(request.TableNumber), request.TableNumber))
            {
                var table = await this.dbContext
                    .AggregateRoot<Table>()
                    .FindByNumber(request.TableNumber)
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);

                if (table == null)
                {
                    return CommandResult.Fail(ResultStatus.NotFound, "Could not find table");
                }

                table.Use(request.CorrelationId);

                await this.dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

                this.logger.Information("Table is in use and is no longer available");

                return CommandResult.Success();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose, because you set an Id on the OrderEntity, EF "thinks" that it's an existing entity in the table. Can you try to set it to Guid.Empty?

Comment: @Lars I'll give it a go and let you know, but I think it'll try to save it with all 0s as that's still a valid GUID

Comment: It's a bit hard to work out exactly what the relationship between these entities is intended to be, but a few things do stand out. 1) when working with aggregates/graphs and you want to manipulate children, it's advisable to eager load the children.(Table.Orders) 2) Check if the DB is set up for ID to pre-populate with new rows. (default of NewId or NewSequentialId) You may need to mark the ID column with `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` to treat as a generated default. This will ignore any ID value you might populate to keep NRT happy for non-null ID fields.